# Increase static pressure

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I have an application (a tube with parts in it) which needs a certain static pressure in it in order to contain a sustainable air flow. Unfortunately the fan I wanted to use in a push-configuration is not able to create this pressure. Thus I thought that I could install another fan with a higher cfm at the end of the tube (in pull-configuration), and thereby increasing the static pressure? Would that be useful, or is there another way to increase the static pressure in the tube?
Schematic is:
[image]

Neither F1 or F2 are able to provide the necessary static pressure alone.

Comment: I am not so sure about your configuration, could you add a sketch? What  happens if you only use the other fan?

Comment: I hope this drawing is enough, if not, please note.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say the blowers need to provide static pressure? Wouldn't F2 reduce the pressure in the tube? Anyhow, be reducing the pressure in the tube F1 is more likely to have a higher flow rate

Comment: If F2 is blowing outwards, and F1 inwards, then the static pressure during the tube (inside are obstacles) should be higher, afaik.

Comment: actually you only need a "high" static pressure in the tube with a single fan set-up because this is what will make the air flow through the pipe. At the end of the pipe the air will have the ambient pressure again. When you have to much pressure loss inside the pipe caused by obstacles you have a very low/no air flow. With the additional fan at the end of the pipe the pressure inside of the pipe can be lower than the ambient pressure, because F2 will rise the pressure enough so that the air can exit the tube.

Comment: Thus if I need a certain Delta p for air flow through the tube, and F1 is not able to provide that, I can add the Delta p of the second fan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the air through the pipe, the pressure rise of the first fan has to be so high, that the pressure-loss within the tube is compensated.

Since your first fan (F1) is not powerful enough you can add a second fan (F2) to rise the pressure at the end of the pipe to ambient pressure, or use a more powerful fan (F3) instead.

[image: setch]

The sketch shows the static pressure on the y-axis and the tube at the x-axis